# TF command line: what is the analog of "svn -u status"?

Tags: command-line

Is there a simple analog of `svn --show-updates status` in TF command line?

What I mean is how can I review the list of files with changes checked in to TFS server which I did not get to my workspace, without getting these changes into this workspace.

I tried to find similar switch in `tf status`, but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the /preview switch on the [tf get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) command.

E.g. tf get $/MyTeamProject/MyBranch /recursive /preview

Comment: Thanks, you're just in time :).

After more attempts I have found the same way.
I was even going to publish an answer to my own question.
The only difference is that I used "." instead of repository path.
This is my working command line:

`tf get /recursive /preview .`

Comment: Nevertheless I must note that this command line shows server changes, but does not show local changes, unlike the svn command I was searching the analog for.

Comment: Ok, for server changes you could use the corresponding, tf checkin /validate this will show you the pending changes in your workspace. Without checking in. You can also use the TFS powertools command [tfpt uu]{http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/09/03/using-tfpt-command-line-tool.aspx} this will undo any files checked out which are unchanged. Finally look at tf diff to see if that meets your needs